# Generating Pear file when using ConceptMapper Annotator

Tags: installation, uima

I have an UIMA project that uses the ConceptMapper Annotator. I would like to know how to set up the following:

1. How to specify the `TokenizerDescriptionPath`?
   I have used the macro `$main_root/descriptors/conceptMapper/primitive/OffsetTokenizer.xml`, but when I was trying to install the pear file,  the installer throws exceptions complaining that the file `$main_root/descriptors/conceptMapper/primitive/OffsetTokenizer.xml` could not be found
2. How to set up the value for the `DictionaryFileName` (A file containing the dictionary)?
   In the GUI window for setting up this resource, I've filled the URL value with `$main_root/data/dict/concepts.xml` (my dictionary file) but at the installation time, the installer throws exceptions complaing that
   Verification of uima-pipelines failed:

   `org.apache.uima.resource.ResourceInitializationException: Initialization of annotator class "org.apache.uima.conceptMapper.ConceptMapper" failed.
   Caused by: org.apache.uima.resource.ResourceAccessException: The Resource /ConceptDetector/ConceptMapper/DictionaryFile requires parameters, none were specified.
               at org.apache.uima.resource.impl.ResourceManager_impl.getResource(ResourceManager_impl.java:221)
               at org.apache.uima.impl.UimaContext_ImplBase.getResourceObject(UimaContext_ImplBase.java:295)
               at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.AnnotatorContext_impl.getResourceObject(AnnotatorContext_impl.java:175)
           ... 33 more`

Answer (score 3):

1. I had similar problems with the Concept Mapper. The way I solved the TokenizerDescriptorPath problem was to first create a PEAR file with the OffsetTokenizer as its main descriptor and the dependent classes. Then you can install this pear file locally and then set `TokenizerDescriptorPath` to: `C:\path\to\your\pear\file\OffsetTokenizer_pear.xml`. Otherwise there appears to be a CLASSPATH inheritance problem. The CLASSPATH does not seem to be passed from the ConceptMapper to the OffsetTokenizer once it is in the PEAR file. I found some great information on the GMANE listserver. [user.uima.apache.org ConceptMapper Pear File Thread](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.apache.uima.general/3991)
2. I have set `DictionaryFileName` to `file:dict/testDict.xml` and this seems to work. To avoid getting a problem at save time you can add resources as a source folder.

When exporting the ConceptMapper to a PEAR file, I have both the resources and bin folder in the CLASSPATH. I have since expanded the Concept Mapper to have other annotators and it is working in a pipeline. It is all exportable to PEAR files which pass the verification step. It also works before export, locally in Eclipse.

Good Luck